# Sql error in C# winform project (error number:102,state:01,class:15)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

In my C# winform project I want to make, when the user clicks on the Reg No dropdown list, the
user can see the previously registered registration numbers appearing in the drop
down list. When the user selects a registration number, it needs to work as a Search
function when user changes the text of this and need to fill all other fields in the form
by focusing the Reg No from the Database Table. Currently when I register a student it shows in dropdown list but when I click that it shows below sql error.

[Sql Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFEi.png)

(line 93 is : `SqlDataReader Re = cmd.ExecuteReader()`)

---

Code for dropdown list

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ActiveControl = txtFirstName;
            try
            {
                string filler = cbRegNo.SelectedItem.ToString();
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE regNo = '" + filler + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(filler, con);
                SqlDataReader Re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (Re.Read())
                {
                    txtFirstName.Text = Re.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    txtLastName.Text = Re.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    dobpicker.Text = Re.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    string gender = Re.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    if (gender == "Male")
                    {
                        MaleButton.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FemaleButton.Checked = true;
                    }
                    txtAddress.Text = Re.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = Re.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    intMobileNo.Text = Re.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    intHomeNo.Text = Re.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    txtParentName.Text = Re.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    txtNIC.Text = Re.GetValue(10).ToString();
                    intContactNo.Text = Re.GetValue(11).ToString();
                }

                con.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error\n" + ex);
            }
        }
```

---

Full Code is shown below.

TIA <3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Skill_International
{
    public partial class Registration_Form : Form
    {
        public Registration_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Fillcombo();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LALITHA_V\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Skill_International;Integrated Security=True");

        void Fillcombo()
        {
            string quary = "SELECT * FROM Registration ;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(quary, con);
            SqlDataReader readerr;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                readerr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (readerr.Read())
                {
                    string regNo = readerr.GetString(0);
                    cbRegNo.Items.Add(regNo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ActiveControl = txtFirstName;
            try
            {
                string filler = cbRegNo.SelectedItem.ToString();
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE regNo = '" + filler + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(filler, con);
                SqlDataReader Re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (Re.Read())
                {
                    txtFirstName.Text = Re.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    txtLastName.Text = Re.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    dobpicker.Text = Re.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    string gender = Re.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    if (gender == "Male")
                    {
                        MaleButton.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FemaleButton.Checked = true;
                    }
                    txtAddress.Text = Re.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = Re.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    intMobileNo.Text = Re.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    intHomeNo.Text = Re.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    txtParentName.Text = Re.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    txtNIC.Text = Re.GetValue(10).ToString();
                    intContactNo.Text = Re.GetValue(11).ToString();
                }

                con.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error\n" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string regNo = cbRegNo.Text;
                    string deleterec = "DELETE FROM Registration WHERE regNo='" + regNo + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmand = new SqlCommand(deleterec, con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted !", "Delete");
                }
                else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string regNo = cbRegNo.Text;
                string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
                string dateOfBirth = dobpicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string gender;
                if (MaleButton.Checked)
                {
                    gender = "Male";
                }
                else
                {
                    gender = "Female";
                }
                string address = txtAddress.Text;
                string email = txtEmail.Text;
                int mobileNo = int.Parse(intMobileNo.Text);
                int homeNo = int.Parse(intHomeNo.Text);
                string parentName = txtParentName.Text;
                string nic = txtNIC.Text;
                int parentNo = int.Parse(intContactNo.Text);

                string query = "INSERT INTO Registration(regNo,firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth,gender,addresses,email,mobilePhone,homePhone,parentName,nic,contactNo) VALUES('" + regNo + "','" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','" + dateOfBirth + "','" + gender + "','" + address + "','" + email + "','" + mobileNo + "','" + homeNo + "','" + parentName + "','" + nic + "','" + parentNo + "')";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Added", "Register");
                cbRegNo.Items.Add(cbRegNo.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string regNo = cbRegNo.Text;
                string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
                string dateOfBirth = dobpicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string gender;
                if (MaleButton.Checked)
                {
                    gender = "Male";
                }
                else
                {
                    gender = "Female";
                }
                string address = txtAddress.Text;
                string email = txtEmail.Text;
                int mobileNo = int.Parse(intMobileNo.Text);
                int homeNo = int.Parse(intHomeNo.Text);
                string parentName = txtParentName.Text;
                string nic = txtNIC.Text;
                int parentNo = int.Parse(intContactNo.Text);

                string update = "UPDATE Registration SET regNo = '" + regNo + "', firstName = '" + firstName + "',lastName = '" + lastName + "',dateOfBirth = '" + dateOfBirth + "',gender = '" + gender + "',addresses = '" + address + "',email = '" + email + "',mobilePhone = '" + mobileNo + "',homePhone = '" + homeNo + "',parentName = '" + parentName + "',nic = '" + nic + "',contactNo = '" + parentNo + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated", "Update");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbRegNo.Text = string.Empty;
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();
            dobpicker.ResetText();
            MaleButton.Checked = false;
            FemaleButton.Checked = false;
            txtAddress.Clear();
            txtEmail.Clear();
            intMobileNo.Clear();
            intHomeNo.Clear();
            txtParentName.Clear();
            txtNIC.Clear();
            intContactNo.Clear();
        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login_Form login = new Login_Form();
            login.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Exit The Application?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {

            }
        }

        private void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Registration_Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbRegNo.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax `string query = "SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE regNo = '" + filler + "'";` looks dangerously open to injection; I strongly recommend parametrisation.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error from that, you're already experiencing the effects of an injection issue, even if it's not due to an attack.

Comment: @madreflection This is why I often recommend fixing it as a *correctness* issue more than a *security* issue. Never mix code and data.

Comment: You have other side issues: Need to dispose your SQL objects with `using`. And then you can remove the `finally`. Also remove the empty `catch` block or you will swallow exceptions. Do not use `SELECT *` specify the exact columns. Do not hard-code the connection string, use a settings file.

Comment: @Charlieface: Agreed. 100%.

Comment: Take care of the basics and the hard stuff is less hard.

Answer (score 0):

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(filler, con);

It should be SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

Comment: Good catch. But that means this is a typo and should be closed as such, especially because another command in the same post shows it being done right.